# Python: sub pattern doesn't replace all patterns found

Tags: python, regex, replace

I am trying to get this following code:

```
pattern = r"#(.*?)#"
pattern_obj = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE)
translation = pattern_obj.sub("<li>\\1</li>", translation)
```

to find any text surrounded by #. It replaces the first instance

```
>>><li> TEXT </li>

# More TEXT #

# Even more TEXT #
```

Can someone please help me?

Thanking you in advance!

EDIT:
I just fixed the issue like so.

```
pattern = r"#([^#]*)#"
pattern_obj = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE)
translation = pattern_obj.sub("<li>\\1</li>", translation)
```

Comment: It works for me, even without "re.MULTLINE"

Comment: It's curious that manually excluding the `#` fixed the problem. I would have thought the non-greedy `*?` would have prevented that from being a problem. Maybe the brackets screw up the scope of the `*?`?

Answer (score -1):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a
>   newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any
>   character including a newline.

Since `.` does not match a new line, the expression finds only the first line as a match.

However, setting the `DOTALL` flag won't help either. Since regex special characters are, generally speaking, greedy, you'll end up matching all of the text between the first `#` and the last `#`.

I may be mistaken, but I believe you'll need to do this line by line.

Comment: The `?` after `*` makes it non-greedy.

Comment: Even if the `*` was greedy, once `.` failed to match the new line it would begin backing off the match until it could match the `#`. Therefore, this shouldn't affect the execution at all.